# SharePoint 2013 peoplepicker-searchadforest troubleshoot

Tags: people-picker

In our environment there is two domains: Domain.com & Test.com. The SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm is installed on Domain.com. We found the people picker can only query users under Domain.com. To resolve it we ran the stsadm command:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:ad.Domain.com;forest:test.ad.Domain.com,test\farmadmin,Password" -url http://webapp
```

The comamnd completede successfully. Right after the command completed, all people picker return nothing. Not even the users under Domain.com. I think the passwords are valid.

Later I reset the property back to original status which is nothing:

```
STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "" -url http://webapp
```

Then the peoplepicker back to original status. (Can search users under Domain.com but not for Test.com)
How can I troubleshoot it?

P.S. Before I run above command, I have run this:

```
stsadm.exe -o setapppassword -password 123456
```

Is the 123456 matter? I think it is just a passphrase. Also I only have single server for both WFE and APP. Another server for SQL. Do I need to run the setapppassword at SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the application pool account have no access to the passphrase I setup using "stsadm -o setapppassword".

To solve it, use regedit to modify the permission of "HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure\". Grant read permission to local WSS_WPG group.

refer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2011/02/16/people-picker-why-don-t-you-trust-me.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage